# My sign up form is not working with django python

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my application the sign up is not creating profiles on the backend.
I have tried to use the django forms but I didnt like how they render so I wanted to use custom form but once I click button submit, nothing happens and I check on backend there's no profile.

- My forms.py file looks like this

  ```
  from django.forms import ModelForm
  from django import forms
  from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from .models import Gig


  class GigForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = Gig
          fields = ['title','category','description', 'price', 'photo', 'status']

  class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
      first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
      last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
      email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'email', 'password' )
  ```

  - Models.py File like this

  ```
  class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      about  = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


  def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username
  ```
- signup.html looks like this

  ```html
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="{% static 'img/home-banner.jpg' %}" class="banner">
  <form action="#" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return(validate());">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="well center-block">
                  <div class="well-header">
            <h1 class="text-center "><b>Sign Up</b></h1>
          </br>
                      <hr>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                  </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"
                  name="{{ form.first_name.name }}"
                  id="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}"
                  {% if form.name.value != None %}value="{{ form.first_name.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
                  maxlength="{{ form.first_name.field.max_length }}"
                  {% if form.name.field.required %}required{% endif %}>                                               
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                  </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="txtlname" class="form-control"
                  name="{{ form.last_name.name }}"
                  id="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}"
                  {% if form.name.value != None %}value="{{ form.last_name.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
                  maxlength="{{ form.last_name.field.max_length }}"
                  {% if form.name.field.required %}required{% endif %}>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="txtlname" class="form-control"
                    name="{{ form.username.name }}"
                    id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}"
                    {% if form.name.value != None %}value="{{ form.username.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
                    maxlength="{{ form.username.field.max_length }}"
                    {% if form.username.field.required %}required{% endif %}>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                                  </div>
                  <input type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" name="txtpass" class="form-control"
                  name="{{ form.password.name }}"
                  id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"
                  {% if form.password.value != None %}value="{{ form.password.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
                  maxlength="{{ form.password.field.max_length }}"
                  {% if form.password.field.required %}required{% endif %}>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

          <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                  </div>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="txtmail" placeholder="E-Mail"
                  name="{{ form.email.name }}"
                  id="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}"
                  {% if form.password.value != None %}value="{{ form.email.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
                  maxlength="{{ form.email.field.max_length }}"
                  {% if form.password.field.required %}required{% endif %}>           
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row widget">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block"> Submit </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  ```
- Views.py looks like this

  ```py
  def signup(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
              user.refresh_from_db()
              username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
              user.save()
              raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
              user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
              login(request, user)
              return redirect('home.html')
      else:
          form = SignUpForm()
      return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
  ```

Comment: First you should always display the form errors in your template as well (e.g.`{{ form.non_field_errors}}` and `{{ form.name.errors }}`) so if the form is not valid you'll see the errors. Second, what does `onsubmit=return(validate())` supposed to do? Where is the function `validate()` defined? Third, what do you see in your browser debug tools? In the network tab? Any request submitted to your server?

Comment: I can see that you have not specified the button type type="submit" why not?.  You should all ways specify.

Comment: @dirkgroten I thought its by that onsubmit=return(validate()) but it wasnt. That was just a  js script. Theres no submit submited.

Comment: @Mateo , I have added it and nothing..

Comment: Can you add the Gig model as well?

Comment: So you removed onsubmit on the form and added type=“submit” to the button and still no request when submitting?

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah, nothing.

Comment: Try <input type=“submit”> instead of <button>

Comment: @dirkgroten nop.

Comment: When you say nothing is happening you verified that no request is sent in the network tab of the debug tools, correct?

Comment: Remove action=“#” or set it to “”

Comment: @dirkgroten done that too already

Comment: Then why are you showing the wrong code in your question? You need to update your question with the code you’re using. Note that all the changes we suggested are necessary, your form won’t submit with any of these still in place.

Comment: And you didn’t reply to my earlier question: no request in the network tab at all?

Comment: @dirkgroten Theres nothing in network tab.

Comment: @dirkgroten but actually I do receive a post call on server.

Comment: "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9888"

Comment: Response 200 means form is not valid. Have you added the {{ form.errors }} to display them?

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah its not the form.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your view, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Profile model has different fields from those you are passing in the signup form

in your **Profile Model**

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    about  = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

did you forget to create these fields in your **forms.py**
[this link will help you](https://github.com/Dihfahsih1/django_webapp/blob/master/users/forms.py)

Comment: Thats not the issue.